# How can I use REMO tool to generate seq.dat and seq.txt files?

Tags: software-usage

I am trying to generate `seq.dat` and `seq.txt` files myself, so that I can use them with [REMO](https://zhanggroup.org/REMO/).

I am using `mkseq.pl` script in [REMOv2](https://zhanggroup.org/REMO/REMO.v2.tar.bz2).

The following was my command:

```
user_name@server_name:~/spatial/reconstruction_tools/remo_v2$ perl mkseq.pl /home/spatial/input_pdb/pdb1a6j.pdb 1
PSIPRED finished
user_name@server_name:~/spatial/reconstruction_tools/remo_v2$
```

This command generated four files:

1. `seq.dat`
2. `protein.fasta`
3. `psitmp27331007f0101.blast`
4. `psitmp27331007f0101.fasta`

`seq.dat` is totally empty. `psitmp27331007f0101.blast` is also practically empty. There is no `seq.txt.`

What am I doing incorrectly?